# Google Machine Type API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to get all the Machine Types using the API mentioned in this doc: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/machineTypes/list
But I am not getting the M2 machine types in the API response. https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/machine-types#m2_machine_types
I have tried different zones which are mentioned to have the M2 machines.

Could someone please help me if i am missing out anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access freely to these machine type. You need to request an evaluation (to your Google Cloud sale contact) or to commit for 1 or 3 years their usage.

You can find this description in the [pricing documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/vm-instance-pricing#larger_ultramem)

Comment: Wow, those are expensive instances. Just to evaluate the m2-ultramem-416 is $43,113.58 Just think about having 11 TB of memory at your disposal and the power consumed.

Comment: @JohnHanley, it's for you and your software!